# python - generator yield factors in increasing order (beginner)

Tags: python

I'm working my way through (beginner) exercises in a Python book and I'm having troubles with one of the exercises.

The exercise: modify this generator so that it reports factors in increasing order, while maintaining its general performance advantages (= testing values only up to the square root of the number).

```
def factors(n):
k = 1
while k*k < n:
    if n%k == 0:
        yield k
        yield n // k
    k += 1
if k*k == n:
    yield k
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

EDIT : After the answer I got from NPE, I changed the code into:

```
def factors(n):
k = 1
temp = []
while k*k < n:
    if n%k == 0:
        yield k
        temp.append(n // k)
    k += 1
if k*k == n:
    yield k
for i in reversed(temp):
    yield i
```

This worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for the `n // k`, the factors are already being produced in increasing order.

Instead of yielding `n // k` immediately, you could remember such factors and yield them at the end.

Comment: Thanks! I stored the n//k values and yielded them at the end of the generator. It worked.